# Foundation checkboxes stop working with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, zurb-foundation

If you go here http://passion4web.co.uk/DigiPics/upload and upload a photo, you'll see it brings up some checkbox options to brighten, distort. etc. I am using jquery to clone `#photo-template` so I can use it multiple times but the problem I am having is the checkboxes will not change when clicked.

This only seems to happen when I add foundation checkboxes to the page using javascript. Here is my method of adding them:

```
    var $template = $("#photo-template");
    var $addedPhotos = $("#added-photos"); 
    $addedPhotos.html("");

    if(response.length > 0)
    {
        for(var i in response)
        {
            var options = response[i];
            var template = $template.clone();

            template.find(".photo").attr("src", options['Photo URL']);
            template.find(".brighten").prop("checked", options['Brighten']);
            template.find(".sky").prop("checked", options['Sky']);
            template.find(".grass").prop("checked", options['Grass']);
            template.find(".distortion").prop("checked", options['Distortion']);
            template.find(".description").val(options['Description']);

            $addedPhotos.append(template.html());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the `for` attribute of `label` correctly. An excerpt of your HTML is:

```
<div class="switch round">
    <input type="checkbox" class="sky" name="sky">
    <label for="sky"></label>
</div>
```

The value of the `for` needs to match an `id` of a checkbox. It should be:

```
<div class="switch round">
    <input type="checkbox" class="sky" name="sky" id="sky">
    <label for="sky"></label>
</div>
```

Unfortunately since you are cloning it, you also need to make these `id`'s unique. One possible solution:

```
template.find(".sky")
        .prop("checked", options['Sky'])
        .prop("id", "sky" + i)
        .next() //get the label after it
        .prop("for", "sky" + i);
```